# Какой способ присваивания значений свойств одного объекта другому считается самым удачным в js?

Tags: javascript

Есть объект, пока только в голове, но собранная за несколько дней информация из различных статей стала ураганом Катрин для моего мозга. Поэтому я хочу спросить у вас, как лучше организовывать объекты и присваивать им значения, находящиеся в других объектах?

Другими словами, есть объект и есть value object со значениями. Как сделать максимально правильно с точки зрения религии js, но при этом максимально ооп'шно и чтоб ещё оптимально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы имеете в виду копировать в дефолтный объект обозначенные свойства из другого, то можно списать из какого-нибудь фреймворка, например из `underscore` метод [`_.extend()`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) ([исходник](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-85)):

```
_.extend = function(obj) {
    if (!_.isObject(obj)) return obj;
    var source, prop;
    for (var i = 1, length = arguments.length; i < length; i++) {
        source = arguments[i];
        for (prop in source) {
            if (hasOwnProperty.call(source, prop)) {
                obj[prop] = source[prop];
            }
        }
    }
    return obj;
};
```

И пример использования:

```
_.extend({name: 'vas'}, {age: 50});
=> {name: 'moe', age: 50}
```

jQuery тоже предлагает [свою версию](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) `extend()`.